# Export PDF Values from specific textfields and import them into specific Cells in Xls file

Tags: excel, vba, windows, csv, acrobat

I have the following Macro, but it doesn't work.
I have installed Adobe Acrobat Pro.
From one side I'm afraid I'm not in possession of all the References I need (It would be a great help already to know the list of references required and how to get them. For instance I don't have Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library.).

At the moment I'm stuck at the error: "Property or method not supported by the object" in reference to the line SHIPSNAME = pdfDoc.GetField("SHIPSNAME CREWLIST").Value.

Please please, put me on the right path to get this problem solved. It is very important for my job

```
Sub ImportaDaPDF()

    ' Imposta il percorso del file PDF
    Dim pdfPath As String
    pdfPath = "C:\Users\@@@@\Desktop\Document.pdf"  ' Sostituisci con il percorso del tuo file PDF
    
    ' Crea un oggetto Acrobat
    Dim acrobatApp As Object
    Set acrobatApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    ' Crea un oggetto PDF
    Dim pdfDoc As Object
    Set pdfDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    ' Apri il file PDF
    If pdfDoc.Open(pdfPath) Then

        ' Estrai i valori dai campi testo
        Dim SHIPSNAME As String
        SHIPSNAME = pdfDoc.GetField("SHIPSNAME CREWLIST").Value
        
        Dim FLAGSTATE As String
        FLAGSTATE = pdfDoc.GetField("FLAGSTATE CREWLIST").Value

        ' Chiudi il file PDF
        pdfDoc.Close

        ' Chiudi l'applicazione Acrobat
        acrobatApp.Exit

        ' Inserisci i valori nelle celle specifiche di Excel
        Dim wsShip As Worksheet
        Set wsShip = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1")  ' Sostituisci con il nome del tuo foglio
        wsShip.Range("A4").Value = SHIPSNAME

        ' Inserisci i valori nelle celle specifiche di Excel
        Dim wsPortCall As Worksheet
        Set wsPortCall = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Page 2")  ' Sostituisci con il nome del tuo foglio
        wsPortCall.Range("B4").Value = FLAGSTATE

    Else

    MsgBox "Errore durante l'apertura del file PDF. Dettagli: " & Err.Description

End If

End Sub
```

I need to extract the values from specific textfields of my PDF Doc and import those values into specific Cells of an Xls file.
I have tried, first, a longer procedure, basically I was sending the values as text into an e-mail's body, copy and paste them into a CSV file, but it didn't worked, not even a bit, because the same macro I use to import data from CSV file wouldn't work in this other case

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using a test PDF form:

```vb
Private Sub ReadPdfFormFields()
    Dim jso As Object, text1, text2 As String
    
    With CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        .Open "C:\temp\Test.pdf"        'load the file
        Set jso = .GetJSObject
        
        ' get the information from the form fields
        text1 = jso.getField("FieldNumber1").Value
        text2 = jso.getField("FieldNumber2").Value
    
        Debug.Print "Values read from PDF: " & vbLf & text1 & vbLf & text2
        .Close        'close the file
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.